# Why does Gson Preconditions fail in this instance?

Tags: java, android, deserialization, gson, ormlite

I am writing a deserializer for the class `ForeignCollection`, which is `abstract`, and provided to me in the [ORMLite Android Library](http://ormlite.com/sqlite_java_android_orm.shtml).  See my code below.

```
public class ForeignCollectionDeserializer implements JsonDeserializer<ForeignCollectionDeserializer> {
    @Override
    public ForeignCollection deserialize(JsonElement jsonElement, Type type, JsonDeserializationContext jsonDeserializationContext) throws JsonParseException {
        ...
    }
}
```

I have also tried implementing `JsonDeserializer<?>` and `JsonDeserialzer` (with no generic type)

I'm using `GsonBuilder.registerTypeAdapter` to register the deserializer.

```
GsonBuilder gb = new GsonBuilder();

gb.registerTypeAdapter(ForeignCollection.class, new ForeignCollectionDeserializer());
Gson gson = gb.create();
```

However, `registerTypeAdapter()` is throwing this:

```
06-11 11:27:27.937: E/AndroidRuntime(15197): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
06-11 11:27:27.937: E/AndroidRuntime(15197): Process: com.myapp, PID: 15197
06-11 11:27:27.937: E/AndroidRuntime(15197): java.lang.IllegalArgumentException
06-11 11:27:27.937: E/AndroidRuntime(15197):    at com.google.gson.internal.$Gson$Preconditions.checkArgument($Gson$Preconditions.java:42)
06-11 11:27:27.937: E/AndroidRuntime(15197):    at com.google.gson.GsonBuilder.registerTypeAdapter(GsonBuilder.java:448)
```

I am stepping through the code and I get to the offending piece, from `GsonBuilder` below.

```
public GsonBuilder registerTypeAdapter(Type type, Object typeAdapter) {
    $Gson$Preconditions.checkArgument(typeAdapter instanceof JsonSerializer<?>
            || typeAdapter instanceof JsonDeserializer<?>
            || typeAdapter instanceof InstanceCreator<?>
            || typeAdapter instanceof TypeAdapter<?>);
    if (typeAdapter instanceof InstanceCreator<?>) {
        instanceCreators.put(type, (InstanceCreator) typeAdapter);
    }
```

I evaluated `typeAdapter instanceof JsonDeserializer<?>` in debug mode and found that it is actually `false`

Actually I've evaluated *all* of these:

- `typeAdapter instanceof JsonDeserializer`
- `typeAdapter instanceof JsonDeserializer<ForeignCollection>`
- `typeAdapter instanceof JsonDeserializer<?>`

They are all false.

How is this so, when I have declared `typeAdapter` as an `Object` of type `ForeignCollectionsDeserializer`, which implements `JsonDeserializer`?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It turns out that I had multiple incorrect imports.

I was accidentally importing another libraries implementation of Gson's `JsonDeserializer`, which caused the code to compile, but fail the `instanceof` conditional.

smh